# pytest clear test memory after yield

Tags: memory, pytest, torch

I wrapped all of my pytests tests with the following fixture:

```
import pytest
import nvidia_smi

def gpu_memory_used():
    nvidia_smi.nvmlInit()
    device_count = nvidia_smi.nvmlDeviceGetCount()
    assert device_count == 1, 'Should be 1 GPU'
    handle = nvidia_smi.nvmlDeviceGetHandleByIndex(0)
    info = nvidia_smi.nvmlDeviceGetMemoryInfo(handle)
    used_memory = info.used
    nvidia_smi.nvmlShutdown()
    return used_memory


@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def check_gpu_memory():
    memory_used_before_test = gpu_memory_used()
    yield
    memory_used_after_test = gpu_memory_used()
    assert memory_used_after_test == memory_used_before_test
```

Now I have the following dummy test function that runs small training:

```
import torch
import torchvision
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torch.optim as optim
import shutil



class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1, 10, kernel_size=5)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(10, 20, kernel_size=5)
        self.conv2_drop = nn.Dropout2d()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(320, 50)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(50, 10)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = F.relu(F.max_pool2d(self.conv1(x), 2))
        x = F.relu(F.max_pool2d(self.conv2_drop(self.conv2(x)), 2))
        x = x.view(-1, 320)
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = F.dropout(x, training=self.training)
        x = self.fc2(x)
        return F.log_softmax(x, dim=-1)


def training(work_dir, epoch, network, optimizer, train_loader, log_interval, train_counter, train_losses):
  network.train()
  for batch_idx, (data, target) in enumerate(train_loader):
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    output = network(data)
    loss = F.nll_loss(output, target)
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
    if batch_idx % log_interval == 0:
      print('Train Epoch: {} [{}/{} ({:.0f}%)]\tLoss: {:.6f}'.format(
        epoch, batch_idx * len(data), len(train_loader.dataset),
        100. * batch_idx / len(train_loader), loss.item()))
      train_losses.append(loss.item())
      train_counter.append(
        (batch_idx*64) + ((epoch-1)*len(train_loader.dataset)))
      torch.save(network.state_dict(), f'{work_dir}/model.pth')
      torch.save(optimizer.state_dict(), f'{work_dir}/optimizer.pth')


def validating(network, test_loader, test_losses):
  network.eval()
  test_loss = 0
  correct = 0
  with torch.no_grad():
    for data, target in test_loader:
      output = network(data)
      test_loss += F.nll_loss(output, target, size_average=False).item()
      pred = output.data.max(1, keepdim=True)[1]
      correct += pred.eq(target.data.view_as(pred)).sum()
  test_loss /= len(test_loader.dataset)
  test_losses.append(test_loss)
  print('\nTest set: Avg. loss: {:.4f}, Accuracy: {}/{} ({:.0f}%)\n'.format(
    test_loss, correct, len(test_loader.dataset),
    100. * correct / len(test_loader.dataset)))



def test_david_torch(tmp_path):

    n_epochs = 3
    batch_size_train = 128
    batch_size_test = 1000
    learning_rate = 0.01
    momentum = 0.5
    log_interval = 10

    network = Net()
    optimizer = optim.SGD(network.parameters(), lr=learning_rate,
                        momentum=momentum)

    random_seed = 1
    # torch.backends.cudnn.enabled = False
    # torch.manual_seed(random_seed)

    train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
    torchvision.datasets.MNIST(f'{str(tmp_path)}/files/', train=True, download=True,
                                transform=torchvision.transforms.Compose([
                                torchvision.transforms.ToTensor(),
                                torchvision.transforms.Normalize(
                                    (0.1307,), (0.3081,))
                                ])),
    batch_size=batch_size_train, shuffle=True)

    test_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
    torchvision.datasets.MNIST(f'{str(tmp_path)}/files/', train=False, download=True,
                                transform=torchvision.transforms.Compose([
                                torchvision.transforms.ToTensor(),
                                torchvision.transforms.Normalize(
                                    (0.1307,), (0.3081,))
                                ])),
    batch_size=batch_size_test, shuffle=True)

    train_losses = []
    train_counter = []
    test_losses = []
    test_counter = [i*len(train_loader.dataset) for i in range(n_epochs + 1)]


    validating(network, test_loader, test_losses)
    for epoch in range(1, n_epochs + 1):
        training(str(tmp_path), epoch, network, optimizer, train_loader, log_interval, train_counter, train_losses)
        validating(network, test_loader, test_losses)
    
    shutil.rmtree(str(tmp_path))
```

Before the test is called I see in `nvidia-smi` that no memory is used, the problem is that after the `yield` memory is still being used.

Is there a way to avoid such behaviour?
I tried clearing the cuda cache etc, but nothing really free the memory.

### Before Test:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 470.82.01    Driver Version: 470.82.01    CUDA Version: 11.4     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Tesla T4            On   | 00000000:00:1E.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   28C    P8     9W /  70W |      0MiB / 15109MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
```

### After Test (for my real case the memory usage is much larger):

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 470.82.01    Driver Version: 470.82.01    CUDA Version: 11.4     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Tesla T4            On   | 00000000:00:1E.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   28C    P8     9W /  70W |      3MiB / 15109MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: How can you know/control or validate the exact nvidia memory release process ? I mean - my concern is that maybe there is some background processes that handling that memory release outside of the current test scope.
Try to manually debug and set a breakpoint on the release phase, and then wait until the memory releases completely and see if it meets your original expected assumption.

Comment: @Moshe even waiting for hours it won't get released. It's release only when the test closes. I was thinking if there is a way to run the test->close it-> and just get the result from it

Comment: Regardless to the test, can you generally validate that nvidia_smi.nvmlShutdown() is giving the expected result ?  I want to eliminate the possibility that pytest framework, or generally Python holds a reference to some nvidia resource.

Comment: yes, if the test does not contain anything that relates to the GPU it works fine